# Trying to simulate a basic op-amp intrgrator but cannot seem to find any error in my circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator

I'm sure I am doing some very basic error I cannot seem to find it
[image]

The yellow wave is a square input and i want the triangle wave output

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring R2, a 12V input means almost 15mA, so a dv/dt at the output of almost 150V/ms until it saturates. At 20ms/div it will change 10V in about 1/200 of a division. So the ramps are there, just not visible.

You will need much higher resistor values to change, say, 10V in 10ms or 1V/ms. Like 150 times higher. Or lower the input voltage by a similar factor. Or increase the capacitor value. Or increase the input frequency (but the 741 is pretty sluggish).

Answer (score 2):

The integrator is *too fast*. +12V at the input will produce this input current:

$$ I_{IN} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} = \frac{12V}{820\Omega} = 14.6mA $$

Ignoring R2, all this current passes through C1, causing the voltage across C1 (which is ultimately the output of op-amp U1) to change at a rate calculated using equation which relates voltage across a capacitor to current through it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{IN} &= C_1\frac{dV}{dt} \\ \\
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac{I_{IN}}{C_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{14.6mA}{0.1\mu F} \\ \\
&= 146\frac{kV}{s} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

That's not a typo; the op-amp output rises at a rate of *146 thousand* volts each second, when +12V is applied at the input of your integrator. Put another way, that's 0.146V per *microsecond*. Similarly it would fall at that same rate if the input were −12V.

In other words, it would take the following amount of time for that output to go from −10V (where the op-amp output is saturated near the negative supply potential) to +10V (saturated near the positive supply), and vice versa:

$$
\begin{aligned}
T &= \frac{(+10V) - (-10V)}{146000\frac{V}{s}} \\ \\
&= \frac{20V}{146000\frac{V}{s}} \\ \\
&= 137\mu s
\end{aligned}
$$

Given that the horizontal time base of your oscilloscope display is 20 milliseconds per division, what you are seeing is the op-amp output slewing up/down so fast, that it saturates near one or the other of the supply potentials in only the first 137μs of a single 20ms division.

To see the nice triangular waveform you expected, possible solutions are:

- Increase the input signal frequency, and reduce the oscilloscope time-base commensurately, so that the input swaps between −12V and +12V in less than 137μs, too short a time for the op-amp output to reach ±10V.
- Increase R1, or C1, by a large amount. Increasing R1 will reduce input current, so the capacitor charges slower. Increasing C1 will have the same effect. Remember that output slew rate is:
  $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{I_{IN}}{C_1}=\frac{V_{IN}}{R_1C_1}$$
  If you increase R1 (or C1) by a factor \$X\$, you *decrease* output slew rate by that same factor. Nothing is stopping you changing both R1 and C1 simultaneously. if you doubled both, you can expect a reduction in output slew rate by a factor of 2 × 2 = 4.

  If you increase R1, be sure to keep \$R_2 >> R_1\$.
- Reduce input signal amplitude. 12V is obviously too much here, and reducing it to 60mV (a factor of 200) will slow the output slewing by a factor of 200. This is a very small input though, potentially comparable with noise and bias currents present in the system. Don't be surprised to see noise/distortion/offset, especially when using an old and poor quality device like the 741.

Answer (score 1):

You have built a 200 Hz low-pass filter with gain of 10x are feeding it with 45 Hz.

So with those values, you will not see any ramps as the ramp is very quick compared to the frequency of the signal.

Also the gain being 10x, the 10V signal will not be a 100V output but limited to near 12V due to 12V supplies. The op-amp is saturated, not linearly amplifying.

The resistances are also quite low, 10V in means 12mA current, if the output were linear. It might be best to inrease the input reaistor and use smaller input voltage for testing.

And higher frequency or make the integration time longer.